# Why ionic app is working with cross-origin without webview plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, webview, ionic4

I'm working with Ionic 4 and until now i made it work it without the webview plugin, but i dont know why/how the app can make cross-origin call without problems.

For me if i use some native plugin like cordova-plugin-file | cordova-plugin-camera i should have to install cordova-plugin-ionic-webview, but is not the case, the application is working fine with cordova plugin without the cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

But because i had to show images saved in the device (using the img tag) i had to install cordova-plugin-ionic-webview and after that the cross-origin doesn't work any more (the server don't return the good header).

So my question are:

- Why i can use cordova plugin (access to native code) without cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
- Why i can make cross-domain if i remove cordova-plugin-ionic-webview, even if the server don't return the good header (for me every ionic app is an webview)
- Why adding cordova-plugin-ionic-webview make the CORS active ?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova plugins are generally not dependant on the webview type or other plugins like ionic-webview.

By default (without a plugin that changes the webview) cordova uses the iOS UIWebView component which does *not* enforce CORS policies.

The cordova-plugin-ionic-webview plugin will replace the UIWebView with the more recent WKWebView which *does* enforce CORS policies.

Comment: ok, maybe for ios/apple is the case, but why in android is the same?, what i sow is that without ionic-webview all reference are with file: prefix, and with the ionic-webview all are in http and localhost, and this why CORS came active.

But why ionic-webview add http? i think that the ionic-webview doc is not clear https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/webview

Comment: ok, after reading again the doc, i think i understand why. If i use the plugin, i will not use the webview OS, i will use one webview compiled with the app and this one will be used with http protocol, so CORS will be active. So all ionic app will use webview but the plugin add custom webview.